# Azure bot name cannot be saved

Tags: azure, botframework

Azure is not saving the bot name that I am trying to set, see recording:
https://share.vidyard.com/watch/JJfpLv2erypyWRFPaAfGgG?

I do recognize this problem for other browser but now it also happens from Edge.. It is there for over a year, what to do?

Comment: This is a known issue and a fix for this is live now. Could you try and see if the problem still persists? I tried to test it on my Edge browser and was able to successfully update the display name.

Comment: First 3 times it was forgotten when trying to save from Edge/Chromium but now when checking in Legacy Edge it seems saved.. let's pray it stays that way, thanks!